# 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GTA.Vector2>' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method

Tags: c#, porting

Need help with C#,problem is that I am porting code from VB.NET to C# I port by myself and then check into translators but my problem is that `Error    14  'System.Collections.Generic.List<GTA.Vector2>' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GTA.Vector2>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and problem of code is

```
private void GraphicsEventHandler(object sender, GTA.GraphicsEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TSkeleton s in skeletonList)
    {
        if (s.bonePos2D.Count > 0)
        {
            //e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item(0).X, s.bonePos2D.Item(0).Y, s.bonePos2D.Item(1).X, s.bonePos2D.Item(1).Y, 2, Color.White)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[1].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[1].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[2].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[2].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.Red);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[1].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[1].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[3].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[3].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.Red);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[2].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[2].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[4].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[4].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.Blue);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[3].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[3].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[5].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[5].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.Blue);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[4].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[4].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[6].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[6].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.Yellow);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[5].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[5].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[7].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[7].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.Yellow);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[6].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[6].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[8].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[8].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.Orange);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[7].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[7].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[9].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[9].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.Orange);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[1].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[1].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[10].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[10].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.Aqua);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[10].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[10].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[11].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[11].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.Aquamarine);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[10].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[10].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[12].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[12].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.Aquamarine);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[11].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[11].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[13].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[13].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.BlueViolet);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[12].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[12].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[14].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[14].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.BlueViolet);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[13].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[13].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[15].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[15].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.CadetBlue);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[14].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[14].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[16].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[16].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.CadetBlue);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[15].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[15].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[17].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[17].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.GreenYellow);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[16].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[16].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[18].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[18].Y, s.sizeMulti, Color.GreenYellow);

            for (Int16 c = 0; c <= 19; c++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(s.bonePos2D.Item(c).X, s.bonePos2D.Item(c).Y, s.sizeMulti * 2, s.sizeMulti * 2, Color.White);
            }

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(s.bonePos2D.Item[0].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[0].Y, s.bonePos2D.Item[19].X, s.bonePos2D.Item[19].Y, s.sizeMulti * 4, Color.Red);
```

also there is where I create bones

```
   foreach (TSkeleton s in skeletonList)
    {
        s.bonePos2D.Clear();

        if (!s.p.isOnScreen)
            continue;

        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.Head)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.Neck)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.LeftArmRoll)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.RightArmRoll)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.LeftForearmTwist)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.RightForearmTwist)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.LeftHand)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.RightHand)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.LeftFinger1)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.RightFinger1)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.Spine)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.LeftThigh)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.RightThigh)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.LeftCalfRoll)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.RightCalfRoll)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.LeftFoot)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.RightFoot)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.LeftToe)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.RightToe)));
        s.bonePos2D.Add(CoordToScreen(s.p.GetBonePosition(Bone.Head) + Vector3.WorldUp * 0.15f));
    }
}
```

And where I create list 
`static List<TSkeleton> skeletonList = new List<TSkeleton>();`
Searched for solution but unsuccessful. Also there is dll called for creating this script named **ScriptHookDotNet**

Thanks For help.
Regards, Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `.Item` on every list access.  That meass `s.bonePos2D.Item[16].X` becomes `s.bonePos2D[16].X`.

This is because C# understands how to use [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) correctly.  [`List<T>.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is actually an indexer, which can be seen in the docs, as it's defined as: `public T this[int index] { get; set; }` [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
s.bonePos2D[1] //2nd bonePos2D item
```